# Error in inserting data to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, syntax-error

I'm getting this error when trying to insert data into the database
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add (price, catID, subCatID, title, description) VALUES ('1500', '1', '1', 'aaa'' at line 1**

Here is my code. Could you please help me to solve this problem.

```
require "dbConnect.php";
dbConnect();

$category     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['catID']);
$sub_category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subCatID']);
$title        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$description  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
$price        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
```

I have included the relevant code here

```
$insert_data = mysql_query("INSERT INTO add (price, catID, subCatID, title, description) VALUES ('$price', '$category', '$sub_category', '$title', '$description')");
            if($insert_data === FALSE)
            {
                die(mysql_error());
            }
```

Comment: `ADD` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) which you must quote with backticks if it is used as a table or column name.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski You should turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ADD` is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) which you must quote with backticks if it is used as a table or column name.  If you have an opportunity to change the schema, it is advisable *not* to use a reserved word since you're likely to encounter this again in the future, as will future developers on your code.

```
$insert_data = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `add` (price, catID, subCatID, title, description) VALUES ('$price', '$category', '$sub_category', '$title', '$description')");
//-------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

As you've probably seen already, the `mysql_*()` extension [has been deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), and will eventually be removed. Rather than continuing to write new code with it, it is advisable to start learning prepared statements in PDO or MySQLi.